# Doobie upgrade from 1.0.0-RC2 to 1.0.0-RC4 causes fragments.or not to compile

Tags: scala, scala-cats, doobie

My code (below) is failing to compile after a Doobie library upgrade. `fragments.or(filterFragments: _*)`  `"Cannot resolve overloaded method 'or'"`. Presumably the signature has changed but I cant get it work in the same as it did before the upgrade. Am I missing something?

```
 def statusFilter(queryCriteria: QueryCriteria): Option[Fragment] =
        queryCriteria.statusFilter.map { filters =>
          val filterFragments: List[Fragment] = filters.map {
            case StatusFilter(Open, date)     => statusFilterOpen(date)
            case StatusFilter(Upcoming, date) => statusFilterUpcoming(date)
            case StatusFilter(Closed, date)   => statusFilterClosed(date)
            case _                            => fr""
          }.toList
          fragments.or(filterFragments: _*)
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In RC2](https://javadoc.io/static/org.tpolecat/doobie-core_2.12/1.0.0-RC2/doobie/util/fragments$.html#or(fs:doobie.Fragment*):doobie.Fragment) the method is

```scala
def or(fs: doobie.Fragment*): doobie.Fragment
```

but [In RC4](https://javadoc.io/static/org.tpolecat/doobie-core_2.12/1.0.0-RC4/doobie/util/fragments$.html#or(f1:doobie.Fragment,f2:doobie.Fragment,fs:doobie.Fragment*):doobie.Fragment) that signature was removed and replaced with two different overloads:

```scala
def or[F[_]](fs: F[doobie.Fragment], withParen: Boolean = true)
  (implicit arg0: Reducible[F]): doobie.Fragment


def or(f1: doobie.Fragment, f2: doobie.Fragment, fs: doobie.Fragment*)
  : doobie.Fragment
```

[The RC3 Release Notes](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/releases/tag/v1.0.0-RC3) mention "Improved composability and safety of fragment helpers `(doobie.util.fragments.*)`"

Seems like the goal was to prevent passing zero fragments to the `or` method. If you can construct a `cats.NonEmptyList[Fragment]`, you should be able to pass that directly to the first version that expects an `F[Fragment]` without a `:_*` signal, since NonEmptyList has a `Reducible` instance. `List` does not have a `Reducible` since that typeclass comes with the expectation of the collection being non-empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It now compiles with fragments.or(NonEmptyList.fromListUnsafe(filterFragments). However the end result is now diffrent. Ie actual:
'Fragment("(
 ((collections.end_date is null AND
  collections.start_date <= ? )
  OR
 (collections.end_date >= ? AND
  collections.start_date <= ?))
 OR 
  collections.start_date > ?
 ) ")'
did not equal expected:
'Fragment("(
 ((collections.end_date is null AND
  collections.start_date <= ? )
  OR
 (collections.end_date >= ? AND
  collections.start_date <= ?))
 ) OR (
  collections.start_date > ?
 ) ")'

Comment: If you read the release notes I linked, they mention "when calling methods like and/or, we now wrap the resulting expression in parenthesis." Looks like the `collections.start_date > ?` clause got subjected to that.

Comment: Note: I'm not a Doobie developer so I can't really comment in detail about their intentions. If you disagree with the new behavior of the method, you should [open an issue](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/new)